# How to set a Relay variable as an enum value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, relay, graphql-js

Example fragment:

```
fragments: {
  viewer: () => Relay.QL`
    fragment on Viewer {
      people(first: $limit orderBy: $orderBy) {
        count
        edges {
          node {
            id,
            ${PersonListItem.getFragment('person')},
          },
        },
      }
    }
  `,
},
```

The `orderBy` argument accepts the following enum values: `firstNameASC`/`firstNameDESC`/`lastNameASC`/`lastNameDESC`.

When doing `this.setVariables({orderBy: 'firstName'})` the `orderBy` variable is passed as a string to the GraphQL server.

How do I pass any of these variables into Relay's setVariables without them being sent as strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can now use an enum variable as a string.

### Example

#### Query (`EventsConnectionOrder` is an enum)

```
query($orderBy: [EventsConnectionOrder]){
  viewer {
    events(first:1 orderBy: $orderBy) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Variables

```
{
  "orderBy": "dateASC"
}
```